# Light Mode Appears for a brief moment before Dark Mode Loads on Website

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website, I have gotten a dark mode toggle working and have saved it into localStorage so that when traversing through the website between pages, dark mode is remembered.  However, whenever I switch pages, the old theme is loaded for a very brief moment (0.5s) and then dark mode loads.  I wanted the dark mode to be seamless and stay on between pages.

Every time a user goes to another page, I have a function called initTheme() that adjusts the theme according to the localStorage variable.  How can I get it so that when users are switching pages, dark load is already loaded?

```
function initTheme() {

    var darkThemeSelected =
      localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") !== null &&
      localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") === "dark";

    darkThemeSelected
      ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark") 
      : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");

    if (darkThemeSelected){
      document.getElementById("darkModeText").innerHTML=`Turn Lights On`;
      document.getElementById("darkModeIcon").className="zmdi zmdi-brightness-5";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("darkModeText").innerHTML=`Turn Lights Off`;
      document.getElementById("darkModeIcon").className="zmdi zmdi-brightness-3";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Because you're doing this client side (javascript), you're not going to be able to avoid the initial flash of content. My first suggestion would be to use the new CSS [`prefers-color-scheme`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) media query to use the user's system preferences, otherwise you'll have to rewrite the content service side instead of client side.

Comment: What do you mean by rewrite the content service side?

Comment: Store the user's preference service side, then use a service side language to write the class in the html when it's being rendered. If you're hosting a static website, you won't have this option, but if you're serving with something like go templates or php you will.